# Intermittent unexpected results when moving rows in a DataGridView

Tags: powershell, datagridview, datatable

I have a basic script as per my code below. So the purpose of this is to be able to move records up and down, when pressing the up or down buttons. This works some of the time, but intermittently it will not move a record (but the selected row will still move). Please try out my code, and move the first record up and down a few times, I hope you will soon see what I mean.

Thank you

Adam

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Data")

# Main Form
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(510,450)
$Form.Text = "Test"
$Form.TopMost = $false
$Form.MinimizeBox = $false
$Form.MaximizeBox = $false
$Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$Form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedToolWindow"

# Datasource
$dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("Name")
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("Step")
[void]$dt.Rows.Add("Jack","1")
[void]$dt.Rows.Add("Jayden","2")
[void]$dt.Rows.Add("Dylan","3")
[void]$dt.Rows.Add("Ben","4")

# Datagridview
$DataGrid = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGrid.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,10)
$DataGrid.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200)
$DataGrid.AllowUserToAddRows = $false
$DataGrid.DataSource = $dt
$DataGrid.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 'OnPropertyChanged'
$DataGrid.AutoResizeColumns()
$Form.Controls.Add($DataGrid)

# Up Button
$upButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$upButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,20)
$upButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,40)
$upButton.Text = “Up”
$upButton.Add_Click({
    moveRow -1
})
$Form.Controls.Add($upButton)

# Down Button
$downButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$downButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(320,70)
$downButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,40)
$downButton.Text = “Down”
$downButton.Add_Click({
    moveRow 1
})
$Form.Controls.Add($downButton)

# Function to move record in DataGridView
function moveRow ($direction){

    if ($DataGrid.SelectedRows[0] -ne $null){

        $currentRow = $DataGrid.SelectedRows[0].Index

        # Don't move up if you are at the top
        if (($currentRow -eq 0) -and ($direction -eq -1)){
            return
        }
        # Don't move down if you are at the bottom
        elseif (($currentRow -eq ($DataGrid.Rows.Count - 1)) -and ($direction -eq 1)){
            return
        }
        else {

            # Get Current and New Values
            $currentValue = $DataGrid.Rows[$currentRow].Cells["Step"].Value
            $newRow = $currentRow + $direction
            $newValue = $DataGrid.Rows[$newRow].Cells["Step"].Value

            # Swap Values
            $DataGrid.Rows[$currentRow].Cells["Step"].Value = $newValue
            $DataGrid.Rows[$newRow].Cells["Step"].Value = $currentValue

            # Sort and refresh DataGridView        
            $DataGrid.ClearSelection()
            $DataGrid.Rows[$newRow].Selected = $true;
            $DataGrid.Sort($DataGrid.Columns["Step"], "Ascending")
        }
    }   
}

# Show Form
$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: The reselection of your rows probably interferes with the `datagrid.sort`. As suspending a `datagrid` (and it's child items might be a challenge (see  e.g. httpsackoverflow.com/q/487661) your probably have to reselect your rows upon a datagrid ready event or visa versa: sort your datagrid on a select event...

Comment: Also, as the sorting apparently happens asynchroniously, you might have to disable the `Up` and `Down` buttons until the datagrid is [`sorted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sorted(v=vs.110).aspx) to prevent you start a new sort before the current one is done.